# SURF performance parameters for template matching

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, surf, template-matching

I am working on SURF based template matching in MATLAB. For performance parameters often Repeatability, Precision and recall are considered. But for template which is sub-image of a big image,how to find number of correspondences in Repeatability formula? Shown here:

[image: Performance parameters]

Considering (#Correct matches) after filtering SURF matches by RANSAC. (#matches) as SURF returned matches including inliers and outliers. n1 and n2 as number of interest points detected in original image and Template.

Here I want to rotate the template and record these parameters. Please suggest me if above consideration needs to be modified.